# Parsing stock exchange pcap files using C++

Tags: c++, performance, struct, pcap

In the past few weeks I downloaded pcap data from [NYSE](ftp://ftp.nyse.com/Real%20Time%20Data%20Samples/NYSE%20XDP/) and learned how to parse the pcap files using C++.

I have been able to strip out all the network headers (UDP, IP headers) and get to the payload. I have started writing code to process the payload.

The method I have used so far is to define various structs for [each message type](https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/data/XDP_Common_Client_Specification_v2.1c.pdf). For e.g.

```
struct msg1 {
        uint16_t  msgSize; // 2 bytes
        uint16_t  msgType; // 2 bytes
        uint16_t  time; // 4 bytes
        uint16_t  timeNS; // 4 bytes
        uint8_t   productID; //1 byte
        uint8_t   channelID; // 1 byte 
};                      
        
struct msg34 {  
        uint16_t  msgSize;  // 2 byte   
        uint16_t  msgType;  // 2 byte 
        uint32_t  time;    // 4 byte
        uint32_t  timeNS;   // 4 byte
        uint32_t  symbolIndex; // 4 byte
        uint32_t  symbolSeqNum;  // 4 byte
        u_char    secStatus;    // 1 byte
        u_char    haltCondition;  // 1 byte
        uint32_t  reserved;     // 4 bytes
        uint32_t  price_1;  //  4 bytes
        uint32_t  price_2;  // 4 bytes 
        u_char    ssr;          // 1 byte
        uint32_t  ssrVol;       // 4 bytes
        uint32_t  time;         // 4 bytes
        u_char    ssrState;     // 1 byte
        u_char    mktState;     //1 byte
        u_char    sessionState;   // 1 byte          
};
```

Next, once I determine the appropriate message type from the first 2 bytes of the payload, I use reinterpret_cast to initialize the struct and store the payload data as follows:

```
const uint16_t* msgType = reinterpret_cast<const uint16_t*>(packet+2);
switch(*msgType) {  
    case 34: {
         const msg34* msg34_ = reinterpret_cast<const msg34*>(packet);
         std::cout << *msg34_;
         break; 
    }
}
```

packet here is of type const u_char* that points to the payload which is in binary format.

Some people did not approve the use of reinterpret_cast to initialize the struct citing that it unsafe. **I would like to get some feedback on an alternative method to directly initialize a struct with binary data accessed by the const u_char* pointer named packet.**

Besides, I would also like to get some advice on how I could better structure the [different message types](https://www.nyse.com/publicdocs/nyse/data/XDP_Common_Client_Specification_v2.1c.pdf)
for better code readability and runtime performance. Right now I have to define a struct for each message type and as you can imagine, my struct definition file is pretty long. **Would it be better to define the messages using classes (abstract and real)?**

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

P.S.: If anyone needs any help getting started on a similar project, feel free to reach out and I will share whatever code I have.

Comment: I guess unions as used to do that. At least in C, but not in *standard* C++! Indeed, AFAIK using unions in C++ for this produces an *ill-formed* program (as for reinterpret casts here). The root of the problem lies in the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) (SAR). If the structure is *packed*, the standard way is to use a *memcpy* call (to escape the SAR).

Comment: Did you read a good [C++ programming book](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321992789/samplepages/9780321992789.pdf) ? And the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) ....) ?